# Referencing appender in another appender in logback

Tags: logback

I'm creating a custom logback appender which needs to fall back to another appender in certain situations (typically a failure). What I'm trying to achieve is this :

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="MYAPPENDER" class="my.appender.class">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="MYAPPENDER" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now, I've implemented **AppenderAttachable** in MYAPPENDER and it does seem to work, - the frameworks sets a reference to CONSOLE appender during initialization and I use it all right.

Is it a standard way to go about the case? Is there an alternative to this approach? Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, support for `AppenderAttachable` is likely to be preserved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you printed logback's internal status messages? What does StatusManager say?

Update: After the changes made to the question my answer no longer makes any sense. I am leaving it nonetheless because as an investigation tool about logback, logback's internal status messages can be very helpful.

Comment: No complaints as far as I can say, it seems to be working, I was just curious if this is the intended way to use the 'appender-ref'. Will it sustain further developments you guys are doing?